# Horizontal scroll on table only when width of table set?

Tags: html, scrollable

I want to make a div containing a table scrollable horizontally. Only works when the width is set on the table tag and not td-tags. Why is this?

Fiddle with non-working scroll

```html
<div style="width:300px;background-color:grey;padding:5px">
  <div style="width:100%;overflow:scroll;background-color:yellow;">
    <table style="background-color:red">
      <tr>
        <td style="width:400px">TESTING</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>

</div>
```

Fiddle with working scroll (width on table tag)

```html
<div style="width:300px;background-color:grey;padding:5px">
  <div style="width:100%;overflow:scroll;background-color:yellow;">
    <table style="background-color:red;width:400px">
      <tr>
        <td>TESTING</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try adding `width:100%` and `table-layout: fixed` on `table`

```html
<div style="width:300px;background-color:grey;padding:5px">
  <div style="width:100%;overflow:scroll;background-color:yellow;">
    <table style="background-color:red; width:100%; table-layout: fixed;">
      <tr>
        <td style="width:400px">TESTING</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>

</div>
```